# EaselJS - How is mouse movement accessed?

Tags: javascript, easeljs

Inside an object (created based on [this tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Inheritance/)), I have the following code. In this code, the lines:

```
event.target.x = evt.stageX; 
event.target.y = evt.stageY;
```

are wrong. What should they be to access the mouse movement?:

```
(function() {
    ....
    var p = createjs.extend(Card, createjs.Container);
    p.setup = function() {
         this.on("pressmove", this.handlePressMove);
         ....
         p.handlePressMove = function (event) {
             event.target.x = evt.stageX; //"Event" is wrong. So is "evt"
             event.target.y = evt.stageY;
             stage.setChildIndex(this, stage.getNumChildren()-1);
             stage.update();
         }
       }
}());
```

Comment: `event.clientX` and `event,clientY`

Comment: That does not work, so maybe there is something else wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sample uses `evt.stageX` instead of `event.stageX`. All MouseEvents will have a `stageX` and `stageY`, which is the position the mouse was in when it fired the event. I think your code came from [this tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/) which uses `evt` exlusively.

Additionally, MouseEvents have a `rawX` and `rawY` on pressMove events, which give you the x/y outside of the canvas element. There is no `clientX` or `clientY` on EaselJS MouseEvents.

Here is a quick sample using the `stageX/stageY`.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/suva8vt3/

Snippet:

```
shape.on("pressmove", function(event) {
    shape.x = event.stageX;
    shape.y = event.stageY;
});
```